# Can we divide a PayPal payment?

Tags: php, paypal

My client has a requirement, I'll illustrate :

Suppose someone purchases something(worth $100) from my client's website. Now my clients wants that $85 would go to the owner of that item and $15 my client will keep as commission.

Is this possible ?

Thanks

Comment: The correct answer depends on the details of the business arrangement between the client and the owner. For example, who is selling the item?

Comment: There are 3 entities : My Client, Owner of product and buyer of product. Owner agrees to pay 15% of his earning to my client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Adaptive Payments](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/adaptive-payments) on the PayPal website.

The Adaptive Payments API allows merchants and developers to pay almost anyone and set up automated payments. They can create applications that manage payments, payment preapprovals, and refunds. They can also send money peer-to-peer, **split payments in both parallel and chained models**, accept guest payments, and schedule disbursements. The Adaptive Payments API works on multiple platforms including the web and mobile environments.